# How to Move Google Analytics for a Website to another Email

Tags: google-adsense

1. I opened my Google Analytics with an email me@yahoo.com
2. I set up a webpage in that Google Analytics account www.mysite.com
3. I added a new email to this Google Analytics account me@btinternet.com
4. I want to transfer my Google Analytics account to a new email me@gmail.com, which has never had any Google Analytics accounts/websites on it.
5. Once in my me@gmail.com email Google Analytics account with my site www.mysite.com in it, how do I get rid of any reference to my old emails me@yahoo.com and me@btinternet.com?

Note: I own all emails. I own the website.

6. Then I want to set up an AdSense account in my new email me@gmail.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log into Google Analytics with either your yahoo or btinternet email address.

I'm assuming both have administrator access to the google analytics account (not just the google analytics property).

Add the me@gmail.com address as a user with all permissions at the GA *Account* level.
Log out.
Log back into analytics via your me@gmail.com address.
Once you are sure all your permissions and access are correct, then you can go to the GA admin page and remove the other two email addresses as users from the analytics account.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009702?hl=en

To create an adsense account, make sure you are logged into your google account with your me@gmail.com email address and see the instructions for Create an AdSense account: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/7402253?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics has a notion of "Accounts", which certain users can have varying levels of permissions to. To "transfer" your GA account to a new Google account, the process will consist of first adding the new Google account with admin privileges to your GA account, then removing all other users/permissions from your GA account.

1. Pull up Google Analytics.
2. Click the Admin icon to bring up the Admin tools.

   [image: admin button]
3. Click the User Management icon to bring up user permissions.

   [image: user management]
4. Click the plus button, then Add New Users.

   [image: add new users button]
5. Add your new email address, `example@gmail.com`. Make sure to check ALL of the permissions to make it an admin account.
6. For each other user click "Remove access" and "Remove yourself". Optionally, you may want to log in to your new account and make sure you have access before you remove your current account.
7. Visit AdSense, log in with your new Google account, and create an AdSense account. This is only for AdSense, and is independent of all the other steps.